# check zero parameter and blank string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, function, parameters, zero

This is my code:

```
   JustAName.prototype = {
    statusColoring: function(idx){
     if (idx != ""){
       alert ("1st alert");
     }else{
       alert ("2nd alert");
     }
   }
```

when I call statusColoring function using statusColoring(0), why I don't get 1st alert? but when I call using statusColoring(1) I get 2nd alert?

how is the correct way to pass zero parameter to a function and check it? or how to check the zero/blank parameter?

I have done using idx.length but still can not..

thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
   statusColoring: function(idx){
     if (idx !== ""){
       alert ("1st alert");
     }else{
       alert ("2nd alert");
     }
   }
```

> JavaScript has both strict and type-converting equality comparison.
>   For strict equality the objects being compared must have the same type
>   and:

- Two strings are strictly equal when they have the same sequence of
  characters, same length, and same characters in corresponding
  positions.
- Two numbers are strictly equal when they are numerically equal (have
  the same number value). NaN is not equal to anything, including NaN.
  Positive and negative zeros are equal to one another.
- Two Boolean operands are strictly equal if both are true or both are
  false.
- Two objects are strictly equal if they refer to the same Object.
- Null and Undefined types are == (but not ===).

Answer (score 0):

Because `0 != ""` returns `false`.

I think you should just do with:

```
 if (idx) {
   alert ("1st alert");
 } else {
   alert ("2nd alert");
 }
```